# How do you get the Dev Tunnel url from the HttpContext?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dev-tunnels

How do I get the Dev Tunnel URL from the HttpContext?

I usually got the host address like this:

```
var host = HttpContext.Request.Host;
```

But when I am using a Dev Tunnel I was expecting to get that funky URL they provide you, but I still get localhost. Please help?

Comment: You get what the server returned in the request/response which is at application layer.  The tunnel is at the routing layer.  You can only get the tunnel IP if it is a remote endpoint in the TCP transport layer.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng I will find a different way to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using dev tunnels in Visual Studio, you can use the Environment Variable `VS_TUNNEL_URL`. More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/dev-tunnels?view=aspnetcore-7.0#tunnel-url-environment-variables